# WMS dynamic style: error long XML

Tags: openlayers, javascript, wms, sld

I am using OpenLayers/JS  for webmapping using GeoServer.

I am trying to generate a xml file to change the style of the WMS dynamically but I get a response: "long URI" which I believe is a problem in long XML that I generate.

When I copy the XML generated file and paste it in the GeoServer style directly, it works.

I tried to reduce the character number of the XML file, changing the rules of colors, etc ... but that did not work.

Some suggestions included using POST instead of GET but unfortunately I did not find any way to do that.

How can I pass this long XML file to the GeoServer?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: This is not really a geography or gis question - all you need to do is as you say is use POST rather than GET so as to keep the URL length to a reasonable length. There are many possible javascript libraries that can do this.